# GRUB restarts on GRUB Loading

Tags: linux, grub, arch-linux

I have installed ArchLinux and I want to boot from SSD.

My partitions (in /etc/fstab):
/dev/sdb3 - mounted as /
/dev/sda1 - mounted as /boot [bios_grub on]
/dev/sda2 - mounted as /etc
/dev/sda3 - mounted as /usr
/dev/sda4 - mounted as /opt

I've exectuted `grub-install --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=arch_grub --recheck /dev/sda` and when my computer boots and goes to "GRUB loading" it restarts.

Comment: Have you tried to repair GRUB?